# Why is proguard running in my debug multidex build?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

## Configuration

- `Mutlidex` is enabled.
- `MinifyEnabled` is `true` in `release` only.

## Gradle buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3"
    }
}
```

## Android DSL configuration:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {

        }

        release {

        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix ".debug"
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt")
            proguardFile "proguard-project.txt"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

## Output from `gradlew assembleDebug`:

```
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading program jar [/<>/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/debug/jars/1/1f/combined.jar]
Reading library jar [/<>/build-tools/23.0.3/lib/shrinkedAndroid.jar]
Preparing output jar [/<>/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [/<>/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/debug/jars/1/1f/combined.jar]
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 0.285 secs
```

## I have tried:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

References:

- [Using MultiDex in Android App runs ProGuard twice and only second time with Warnings/Notes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219333/using-multidex-in-android-app-runs-proguard-twice-and-only-second-time-with-warn)
- [What is the default for minifyEnabled for buildType not explicitly scripted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846750/what-is-the-default-for-minifyenabled-for-buildtype-not-explicitly-scripted)
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199630
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `minifyEnabled` to false for the debug build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using multidex to split up your classes into multiple dex files, the Android plugin will internally use **ProGuard** to determine which classes have to be kept in the main classes.dex.

This execution has nothing to do with your own rules or the minifyEnabled flag and can be safely ignored although the log output may be annoying. To suppress the log messages, you can add the following to your build.gradle:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name.startsWith("transformClassesWithMultidexlistFor")) {
    task.logging.level = LogLevel.ERROR
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and investigation. This does work. `level` (`setLevel`) is deprecated. What should we use now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `minifyEnabled false` in the `debug` build type. It is generally there by default when you create a new project. You seem to have removed it.

Comment: `minifyEnabled` is `false` by default: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29847488/950427. You can test via `println android.buildTypes.debug.minifyEnabled`.

Comment: does it work fine when you add the false flag explicitly or still continues to misbehave?

Comment: Yes, proguard still runs. I believe this is a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962.